# Low free disc space please help

Tags: disk-usage

I received a warning of limited space so I deleted a bunch of videos and removed old programs i don't use any more. Then I downloaded bleach bit and ran that but that a warning pops up saying I have even less free space then when I started. please help!

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1       146G   92G   47G  67% /
udev            489M  4.0K  489M   1% /dev
tmpfs           199M  856K  198M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            497M  112K  497M   1% /run/shm
```

Comment: Can you post the output of `df -h`?

Comment: I am not sure what that is. Sorry, very new to this

Comment: Open a terminal and run that command, it should give some info about disk space.

Comment: can you dumb that down a bit more for me, sorry. what terminal, from where?

Comment: cnt alt T, to open terminal but i dont know what to do with it. guess ill punch in df -h and see what pops up

Comment: Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1       146G   92G   47G  67% /
udev            489M  4.0K  489M   1% /dev
tmpfs           199M  856K  198M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            497M  112K  497M   1% /run/shm

Comment: hope thats what you needed :) I can figure some things out!

Comment: According to that, you do have disk space. What makes you think you do not? Are you getting some kind of error or prompt?

Comment: yes I am getting a message saying that I am low on disc space every time the bleach bit finished running.

Comment: @kalena please edit the question if you have information :) And do not forget to empty the trash :)

Comment: trash was emptied, hope i edited the question properly

Comment: Can you post the specific error that you are getting?

Comment: Are you sure you need Bleach Bit? It will  fill the disk ON PURPOSE before cleaning it to remove all trace of old content. So it's normal to have that warning running Bleach Bit --- which by the way used to have a nasty bug, see http://askubuntu.com/questions/427647/strange-folder-in-my-home-folder-after-a-failed-run-of-bleachbit and http://askubuntu.com/questions/267137/is-bleachbit-really-necessary

Comment: no i am not sure i need bleach bit, is there something i can use instead as a crap cleaner?? makes sense thats why i keep getting the message.